# How do I add an ePub to my iPad

Tags: macos, ipad, finder, catalina, books

I have an ePub which I bought outside of the Book Store, and on which there is no DRM. It is sitting on my iMac, running MacOS Big Sur.

I can double click on the ePub and open it in the Books App. From there I can add it to one of my collections. The question is how do I add it to my iPad from there?

As of Catalina, you’re supposed to do this sort of thing in the Finder. Indeed I can see my iPad, and select the Books tab. However, the list of books only shows a few dozen books, when my iPad definitely has hundreds. The list of books doesn’t show my new books, certainly not my collections. Thus there is no check box for me to select and then sync.

What do I do now?

Comment: Does https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl562e1847/mac help?

Comment: @nohillside I get the impression from the article that it doesn’t apply to all books, only the ones from the list. I can’t see how those books got to the list as they’re not from Apple’s Book Store, and I can’t see how to add more books to the list. Certainly the list doesn’t include collections.

Answer (score 2):

Just send the book via AirDrop to your iPad, then click share and after that select the Books app.

Answer (score 0):

I have folder named 'books' under Documents on my Mac for books sourced outside Apple ecosystem.

Via iCloud this folder is available under Files app in iOS. So in iOS I navigate to 'book' folder in Files app and open book I want. From now on I can access it in Books.

Quite surprisingly some sort of syncing is present. If I keep book open in Mac Books app then in iOS it opens on the same spot. I have not observed it working vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I store my epub files in icloud folder on my Macbook then access icloud from file app on iphone. automatically opens the book in iphone book app[image]